# Sql query added to title?

Tags: sql, addition, title, updates

In c# Windows Forms:

I'm having trouble adding a sql query result as text to a ToolStripMenuItem.Text.

The ToolStripMenuItem title should be, the company + how many orders there are in the sql table for this company which should update every x secounds.

Every 5 seconds it adds the query result to the text. My problem is that is "adds" it. 
After the first 5 seconds it looks OK "rexton 1" but 5 seconds after it shows "rexton 1 1" and so on...

Here is my code:

```
 //Rexton ordre klar til bestilling
         SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=" + globalvariables.hosttxt + "," + globalvariables.porttxt + "\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=ha;Persist Security Info=false; UID='" + globalvariables.user + "' ; PWD='" + globalvariables.psw + "'");
                    SqlCommand command = con.CreateCommand();


                    command.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) from bestillinger WHERE firma = @rexton and udlevering BETWEEN @date and @dateadd";
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bernafon", "Bernafon");
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gn_resound", "GN Resound");
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@oticon", "Oticon");
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phonak", "Phonak");
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rexton", "Rexton");
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@siemens", "Siemens");
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@widex", "Widex");

                    con.Open();
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    string result = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

                    con.Close();

                    if (result != "0")
                    {
                        rextonToolStripMenuItem.Text = rextonToolStripMenuItem.Text + " " + result;
                        rextonToolStripMenuItem.ForeColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FF1919");
                    }
```

Answer (score 2):

it is because you are setting `rextonToolStripMenuItem.Text to rextonToolStripMenuItem.Text + " " + result` which is appending to previous text

either set text to **blank** and set it **again** or just say

```
rextonToolStripMenuItem.Text = "rexton " + result
```